# R Shiny: Creating X numbers of numericInput boxes equal to number of variables

Tags: r, shiny, finance, numeric-input

I'm trying to create a finance-related R Shiny application. As of right now, I have a tab to create a custom portfolio, which requires me to have a `numericInput` for each variable in the original `source_file`. This is how the sample `source_file` looks like:

| Date | CSI500 | Shanghai | CSI300 | HSI | STI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | +5% | -2% | +5% | +10% | +12% |
| 2016-01-08 | +3% | +13% | -8% | -3% | +10% |
| 2016-01-15 | +2% | +11% | -3% | +4% | -15% |

Currently, I have to manually hardcode each `numericInput` box for each variable like shown:

```
tabPanel("Custom Portfolio by Weight",
                           sidebarPanel(
                             tags$h3("Create your own Custom Portfolio by Asset Weight"),
                             tags$h4("Input:"),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_csi500", "CSI500 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_shanghai", "Shanghai Stock Exchange (%)",  min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_csi300", "CSI300 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_hsi", "HSI (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_sti", "STI (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_twse", "TWSE (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_msciw", "MSCI World (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_sp500", "S&P500 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_n225", "Nikkei 225 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_lse", "London Stock Exchange (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_asx", "ASX (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
```

However, I would like to create something which could be extensible to any dataframe with different numbers of variables I specify without having to manually hard code them in. I hope anyone will be able to help me out to write a code which is able to read the number of variables in my dataframe (except the Date column) and create that many `numericInput` boxes for each variable. Thank you so much for helping out! I attached my App.R and Global.R below for reference if needed. Cheers!

App.R

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
source("./global.R")

# Defining UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
                navbarPage(
                  "Test App",
                  tabPanel("Custom Portfolio by Weight",
                           sidebarPanel(
                             tags$h3("Create your own Custom Portfolio by Asset Weight"),
                             tags$h4("Input:"),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_csi500", "CSI500 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_shanghai", "Shanghai Stock Exchange (%)",  min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_csi300", "CSI300 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_hsi", "HSI (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_sti", "STI (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_twse", "TWSE (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_msciw", "MSCI World (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_sp500", "S&P500 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_n225", "Nikkei 225 (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_lse", "London Stock Exchange (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             numericInput(inputId = "custom_asx", "ASX (%)", min = 0, max = 100),
                             mainPanel(
                             plotOutput(outputId = "custom_returns"),
                           ), #mainPanel
                ), #tabpanel
                ) #navbarPage
) #fluidPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {

#to output custom_returns for Custom Portfolio by Asset Weight
    output$custom_returns <- renderPlot({
      calculate_portfolio_returns(
        customrange = input$customrange,
        asset_weights = c(input$custom_csi500/100,
          input$custom_shanghai/100,                
          input$custom_csi300/100,
          input$custom_hsi/100,
          input$custom_sti/100,
          input$custom_twse/100,
          input$custom_msciw/100,
          input$custom_sp500/100,
          input$custom_n225/100,
          input$custom_lse/100,
          input$custom_asx/100,
          input$custom_custom/100))
    })
}
  
# Create Shiny Object
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Global.R

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(testit)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#choose source file to work with
file_name = file.choose()
source_file = read_csv(file_name)
source_file$Date = as.Date(source_file$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

########################
calculate_portfolio_returns = function(customrange, asset_weights)
{
  #filter source file by date range specified
  source_file_filtered <- source_file %>% 
    filter(Date >= customrange[1] & Date <= customrange[2])
  
  source_file_filtered_no_date <- source_file_filtered[,2:length(source_file_filtered)]
  
  #create new column called Cumulative_Returns to convert % daily returns
  Cumulative_Returns <- cumsum(source_file_filtered_no_date)
  
  # Extract necessary parameters
  n_cols = ncol(Cumulative_Returns)
  n_assets = n_cols
  
  #To ensure portfolio is always weighted at 100% at all times
  assert(length(asset_weights) == n_assets)
  assert(abs(sum(asset_weights)-1) <= 0.001)
  
  portfolio_returns = data.matrix(Cumulative_Returns) %*% asset_weights
  portfolio_returns_with_date = cbind(source_file_filtered[,1], portfolio_returns)
  g = ggplot(data = portfolio_returns_with_date, mapping = aes(x=Date, y=portfolio_returns)) +
   geom_line(color="blue") + ggtitle(paste("Custom Portfolio Returns from", customrange[1], "to", customrange[2])) +
   geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
    ylab("Portfolio Returns (%)")
  print(g)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo that may be helpful for you.

You can upload a .csv file to the shiny app. It will ignore the first column (or you can modify to specifically remove a date column).

The numeric inputs will be dynamically generated based on the header column names read in.

The demo has a `calc` button, that will store the input data and for further processing (calculating returns). Also added a table to show the entered data.

**Edit**: If upon pressing the `calc` button you want to call your custom function (`calculate_portfolio_returns`), you can add the call to that function in `eventReactive`, since that is dependent on the input button. To pass on the values from the numeric inputs, you can store these values temporarily in a vector `vals`, and then pass `vals` as an argument to the function (see modified code below). In the demo, I call a custom function `calc_sum` that will print the sum of the numeric inputs in the console. One final note, I added an explicit `return` at the end of `input_vals()`, so that `vals` can be shared for use in `output$table`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "upload_file", "", accept = '.csv'),
  uiOutput("num_inputs"),
  actionButton("calc", "Calculate"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$upload_file
    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })
  
  header_vars <- reactive({
    names(data()[-1])
  })
  
  output$num_inputs <- renderUI({
    vars <- length(header_vars())
    if (vars > 0) {
      div(
        lapply(seq(vars), function(x) {
          numericInput(inputId = paste0("var_", x), label = header_vars()[x], value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
        })
      )
    }
  })
  
  input_vals <- eventReactive(input$calc, {
    n_vars <- length(header_vars())
    vals <- c()
    if (n_vars > 0) {
      vals <- sapply(seq(n_vars), function(i) {
        input[[paste0("var_", i)]]
      }) 
    }
    calc_sum(vals)
    return(vals)
  })
  
  calc_sum <- function(vals) {
    print(sum(vals))
  }
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(
      vars = header_vars(),
      vals = input_vals()
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works just fine! Just gotta incorporate this into my app somehow, really appreciate the demo

Comment: However, I just have 1 question for this. What will the variable IDs be if I were to reference the variables in another function in global.R? Will it be input_vals?

Comment: I'm planning to use the numbers inputted into the reactive numericinput boxes that you created for me (which represent the weights of each stock in the list) and create a weighted portfolio consisting of all of the stocks and their respective weights. However, to do that, I will need to set my functions' argument asset_weights to the numericInput from your solution earlier. Do you think you know how I could define my argument asset_weights according to your lines of code? Appreciate it!

Comment: @honnielemons See edited answer - I added more explanation and updated code. It should be relatively easy to pass the `numericInput` values to a custom function. Let me know if this helps.